# Get faces of each uv shell on the python maya api

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to query the faces of each uv shell on a geometry, I'm using maya.cmds but since this needs to run on a callback, I need faster results. I thought about using the api but can't get the same results.

On maya.cmds I use polyEvaluate with the uvShellIds argument. Ex:

```
print maya.cmds.polyEvaluate('pCube1.f[*]', uvShellIds=True)
```

Outputs:

```
[0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L]
```

Only downside is if I query specific faces it will be slow. I thought about using MFnMesh on the api but can't get the same result.
Ex:

```
import maya.api.OpenMaya

mSel = maya.api.OpenMaya.MSelectionList()
mSel.add('pCube1')

num, shellIds = maya.api.OpenMaya.MFnMesh(mSel.getDagPath(0)).getUvShellsIds()
print shellIds
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I read the docs but can't figure out what the result it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The MFnMesh method gives you a list of uv ids in a shell. In a default cube you have 14 uv coords in one shell. The polyEvaluate gives you the shell number of the selected faces (in your case) what are six uvcoords all belonging to one shell. If you call the polyEvaluate with a range of uv coord like `pCube1.map[0:13]`, you will get the same result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in this case I'd like to get the same result of "maya.cmds.polyEvaluate('pCube1.f[*]', uvShellIds=True)" on the maya api. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: Okay, then I have no idea. But since the maya.cmds only call the same functions, I doubt that you will have a speed improvement using maya.api.